# Excel VBA mysql query with string variable

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

So i'm doing this simple sql select from mysql database in my VBA code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT sum(operation_employee_execution_time) FROM employee_operation where employee_last_name like '" & sEmployee & "'"
```

and it is not working. If I do `msgbox(cmd.CommandText)` I see properly formatted SQL query:

[image]

Unfortunately result of that query is nothing (meaning like clause could not find a match), but if I hardcode the value of the variable like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT sum(operation_employee_execution_time) FROM employee_operation where employee_last_name like 'Levkovic'"
```

It works perfectly...

Anyone could give me some advice here? I thought that this will be some sort of encoding problem but adding `"CharacterSet=utf8;"` to my connection string did not help (that column in db is `utf8mb4_bin`)

Comment: Since obviously the issue is not in that line of code you posted (because it works if you hardcode it) you should consider updating your question and provide a [mcve] or the relevant code parts.

Comment: *and it is not working.* Impossible. Either it is executed successfully or it result to error. Empty result is successful execution. *Anyone could give me some advice here?* Enable General log and compare the texts of queries.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` without wildcards? Use `=` instead. Please post full code block (not line snippets) that shows *where* SQL string is defined and message box is raised. Btw- if *sEmployee* comes from user input, you should be using parameterization (else the infamous [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/))!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for input, problem was that the Excel cell that was read to the variable sEmployee had some unicode characters.